# A zombie or alien horror movie whose protagonists are young adults

Tags: story-identification

I recall watching a movie about 4 years ago, it was a sort of horror movie where zombies (or equally dreaded aliens) appeared on the Earth, and they sucked their victim's blood to lay larvae which then settled on the corpse (calling it a zombie for the rest of this question). If I remember correctly, the protagonists were a group (3 to 5 people) of young adults (17~20 years old). One of the first scenes was like this:

> The group searching for their dog (dogs were rare) in the night, when
>   one of them enters on a old abandoned hotel. He climbs the stairs and
>   starts opening every door quietly, calling for his dog and briefly
>   turning on his flashlight. In a room with two beds, he finds the
>   corpse of his dog on the floor, severely thinner and ressecated,
>   lacking all its fur, with a zombie lying behind the corpse. The zombie
>   sees him, and proceeds to desperately and ineffectively crawl to him.
>   He runs away, leaving the room and looking back to see if the creature
>   was still following him. He steps on a broken piece of floor and falls
>   in the lower floor. In the meantime, the creature gets up on its feet
>   and starts running after him. When he gets out of the hotel, he calls
>   his friends and they all run in the side of the street, until they
>   come across a bus and get in it. The bus has a very different design,
>   where the driver seat is located such as the driver faces the left of
>   the bus. They take place of the horrified driver and try to run from
>   the zombie (now at full speed).

I remember these scenes quite vividly, but the rest of the movie is completely forgotten to me. Anyone knows it or a similar story?

Comment: Some of it sounds like [Bad Taste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Taste) and some bits are like [Zombi 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombi_3).

Answer (score 5):

It sounds very similar to [Night of the Creeps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Creeps).

From IMDb:

> In 1959, an alien experiment crashes to earth and infects a fraternity member. They freeze the body, but in the modern day, two geeks pledging a fraternity accidentally thaw the corpse, which proceeds to infect the campus with parasites that transform their hosts into killer zombies.

From the movie:

> "They got Alfalfa. They get in through your mouth and then they lay eggs in your brain, and you walk around while they incubate. You walk around even if you're dead."

An under-rated guilty pleasure that *does* include a zombie dog.

Comment: Sounds like possibly it, though I'll have to find a way to watch this to be sure. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](http://putlocker.bz/watch-night-of-the-creeps-online-free-putlocker.html) site is legit, but it seems to have the movie streaming for free.

Comment: The stream was legit, and the movie was interesting, but it wasn't this one. Thanks for the effort, though!

Comment: Going out on a limb here. There is another zombie movie called [The Video Dead](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0155350/) which also features [a dog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J88xikwVUTQ). This time the dog is named "Chocolate." And again, it's an under-rated classic. It is even meta in that the movie is reality and those who view it, etc... Like the movie [Demons](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089013/).

Comment: @MeatTrademark: While I'm doubting that the original querent is going to accept, I've voted to undelete your comment about *The Video Dead* because it does seem to partially match, and it might help other people searching for it.

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here. There is another zombie movie called [*The Video Dead*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0155350/) which also features [a dog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J88xikwVUTQ). This time the dog is named "Chocolate." And again, it's an under-rated classic. It is even **meta** in that the movie is reality and those who view it, etc... Like the movie [*Demons*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089013/).

> The writer Henry Jordan receives a mysterious TV set and soon he learns that the apparatus is a gateway through which undead come to the world of the living. They kill Henry and the house is sold to another family. The teenager Zoe Blair comes to house to clean it for her parents that are traveling abroad. Her brother Jeff Blair comes later to help Zoe and finds the TV set in the basement. He brings to his room and out of the blue, the stranger Joshua Daniels knocks on the door. Joshua explains that he sent a TV set mistakenly to that address, instead of to the Department of Occult Warfare. Jeff does not believe in Joshua, but soon he leans the truth about the TV of the undead.

Hopefully this is it, though it still *does not match* all of your memories / criteria.

### Trailer